# Extract Blogger.com Video (RTSP or other methods)

Tags: video, media, blogger, rtsp, data-extraction

A client of mine wants to migrate from **Blogger.com** to anywhere, and so far no problem since i can extracts the pages & the content with the Blogger API.

The problem is that the api doesn't help on getting **media such as Videos** that where uploaded via the Blogger.com back-office. The videos can't be found on the youtube or picassa profile, so i guess the blogger/google servers have it.

I noticed that the video (such as : http://www.theextravagants.com/2016/03/crawl.html ) are played with the youtube player and contains an RTSP:// link ( **rtsp://v1.cache5.googlevideo.com/ChoLENy73wIaEQneV3D_QWnzERMYDSANFEgDDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp** ) but i can't open it with VLC or even with a library to extract RTSP like RTSPDump (http://bisqwit.iki.fi/source/ms-rtsp-dump/)

I'm Kinda stuck and i'd like to extract all video to put them on a dedicated server, but i can't event extract One video xD

If you have any idea, i'll test it :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a backup of your video uploaded to Blogger storage, you will have to go to a URL like http://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=CONTENTID and download it from there. (You will need to replace CONTENTID  with its actual value. It can be found in the `id` attribute of the `<object>` tag of the video, in the format `BLOG_video-CONTENTID` )

For example, for the above video, the URL would be http://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=11f36941ff7057de and you can then right-click on the video & using the `Save video as` option save it locally

Comment: It's exactly what i looked for. You're my Hero. 

I'd "+1" if i were 15+ of reputation. 

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the

```html
blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentid=****
```

method is down now. Any updated way for playing google blogger videos by contentId (16 di)

Comment: Maybe the solution here could help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54758474/how-to-get-the-link-from-blogger-video-by-the-video-id)

I am happy not having to work with blogger videos anymore, may the force be with you