# How to get the link from blogger video by the video ID?

Tags: api, blogger

I have found some sites that use their own domain to use embed videos from blogger, example: `https://example.com/blogger/video-play.mp4?contentId=264f2ge544g86h49`.

PS: `https://example.com` is not a domain hosted on blogger, it's outside blogger

`264f2ge544g86h49` is the ID of a video uploaded to blogger.

How is it made? There's a tutorial? I did not find anything about it on https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using

Comment: ID is randomly created, what do you want from this one?

Comment: when you upload a video to blogger, it generates a ID, i want go to that video putting this ID on my domain like the example i showed above, did you got it? I'm talking about the link to fhat video. I think that it's made with a API but i did not found a article about it

Comment: @111111111111 Could you share examples of websites that still embed videos using this method?  Around November 2018, this method stopped working for users

Comment: That actually works. It appears to be a custom API endpoint created by that website. I cannot be sure regarding what logic they use behind the scene to extract the video link from the Video ID but I think they internally use Blogger API to edit/create a post with the content set as the Video ID which is supplied in the URL's query parameter and then from the API response extract the Token required for getting the actual video link. Blogger recently shifted to token-based video links, Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/53440048/933980 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/53397460/933980

Comment: @PrayagVerma I also think that they are creating a blogger post with the Video ID from the URL parameter  `contentId=`, i noticed that when i put a new Video ID on the URL it takes some seconds to load the video, this not happens when i put a Video ID used before, so i think it's creating a blogger post. Can you tell me where can i find this `Token required for getting the actual video link`? Are you talking about the token from this  URL parameter `token=`? https://pastebin.com/Ak3f0h8h

Comment: Yes, that is the token I am referring to. Previously, it was possible to get the actual video link using only the Video ID (Using a format like `https://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=VIDEOID`). This meant that after uploading the video to Blogger, it wasn't required to publish a post. But starting around Nov 2018, they shifted to a token-based video URL (like `https://www.blogger.com/video.g?token=TOKEN`). That token can only be known after the post containing the video is published. This likely happened due to the Video Management option that Blogger introduced around that time.

Comment: @PrayagVerma I checked the `view:soucre` from this link to the video token [link](view-source:https://www.blogger.com/video.g?token=AD6v5dx1MyTRLyJapJGZyxcRPsVFDcS3DMkuGAvOi4Nlmo1rB6TnXe0uqWFW9bWCaeGRZLgV2cxbD1J9mS9a1MDzzpIM0LfI0uiPETeMvnWtxb3Zh-WgHAsCADoX_uCktMK-aJ9GNaA) on the bottom of the page you can see a code in javascript `var VIDEO_CONFIG = {"thumbnail:`...etc

Comment: @PrayagVerma inside this ` VIDEO_CONFIG` there's a parameter `"streams":[{"play_url":"https://r2---sn-o`...etc, this is the actual video link (i guess), i tried to access this link but i got this error `Access to r2---sn-ovnn5gxqxcg-gxje.googlevideo.com was denied`. I think this is the link to `the API response extract the Token required for getting the actual video link`. But how to access this link? As i said i got this error

Comment: @111111111111 Yes, that is indeed the actual video link. Likely you are trying to access the JSON escaped version of the video link. Try to unescape the video link before accessing it and it should work. Here is an example - https://pastebin.com/raw/RjrQG9jp

Comment: @PrayagVerma True, and the url can be easly decoded with this function in JS `decodeURIComponent(url)`. At https://developers.google.com/blogger/ there's only tutorials about simple things like creating/deleting a blogger post, and there's differents API vx.x, i don't know how to start. Let's say that i already have the token needed, how can i retrive the value of  `[{"play_url":"`? There's a tutorial?

Comment: Yes, using the token directly would do away with the step to interact with the Blogger API. You can write a server-side logic in your preferred language which reads the source of `https://www.blogger.com/video.g?token=TOKEN` where `TOKEN` is picked up from the query parameter and extract the video URL from it. I don't think a tutorial for this specific topic would exist but you will be able to find tutorials for similar requirements (aka reading source of a URL) easily

Comment: @PrayagVerma Got it, thanks. This will be easy to accomplish with PHP and Ajax to refresh the video `src`. This was more easy than i thought.

Comment: @111111111111 I have summarized the conversation above into an answer below. Regarding `refreshing the video src`, that wouldn't be required. Like the websites that you mentioned above, you can do a 302 redirect to the actual video URL. This way you can use a consistent video src URL across the website (`https://www.yourwebsite.com/video-player?token=TOKEN`) which redirects to the actual video link after processing at the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the solution that we reached in the comments above. This will require writing server-side logic in the language of your choice to extract the actual video link using the Video ID or Video Token.

The more complicated approach would be using the Video ID directly ( `https://example.com/blogger/video-play.mp4?contentId=VideoID`). You will need to write logic for interacting with Blogger API to edit/create a post using the **VideoID** that you get via the query parameter (obtained from `https://example.com/blogger/video-play.mp4?contentId=VideoID`). The blog post will have the following content -

```html
<object id="BLOG_video-VideoID" class="BLOG_video_class" contentid="VideoID"></object>
```

Now accessing that particular post available in the public Blogger feed via

```
https://www.blogger.com/feeds/BLOGID/posts/default/POSTID?alt=json
```

From the `content.$t`property in the above JSON feed, it would be possible to extract the *Video Token* for the particular video.

Using the *Video Token*, send a GET request to -

```
https://www.blogger.com/video.g?token=VideoToken
```

It would be possible to extract the actual video URL by parsing the response.  The response will be in HTML, the actual URL is present in the JavaScript object with the key `play_url` -

```js
var VIDEO_CONFIG = {
    "thumbnail": "Thumbnail-URL",
    "iframe_id": "BLOGGER-video-VideoID-6712",
    "allow_resize": false,
    "streams": [{
        "play_url": "Actual-Video-URL",
        "format_id": 18
    }, {
        "play_url": "Actual-Video-URL-Higher-Resolution",
        "format_id": 22
    }]
};
```

---

A simpler approach would be starting directly with the Video Token as that would do away with the need for interacting with the Blogger API & Feeds completely.

---

Previously, it was possible to get the actual video link using only the Video ID (Using a format like `https://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=VIDEOID`). This meant that after uploading the video to Blogger, it wasn't required to publish a post. But starting around November 2018, Blogger shifted to a token-based video URL (like `https://www.blogger.com/video.g?token=TOKEN`). That token can only be known after the post containing the video is published. This change likely happened due to the Video Management option that Blogger introduced around the same time